# Find an algorithm to write a given word with this broken keyboard

Tags: algorithms

I am submitting this interview question I have recently found

> Imagine you have a computer keyboard that has all the letters mismatched
>   example:
>   - typing q gives you a
>   - typing w gives you b
>   all 26 letters in the alphabet are there, but typing one letter will give you another one
>
> Restriction: you need to type a word every time, not go character by character
>
> The goals are
>
> - find an algorithm to write a given word with this keyboard
> - estimate its complexity
> - identify the approach limits

**NOTES**

- The restriction means it is not possible to type a single char and observe the result, it is necessary to input a whole word before observing the result

Comment: Cf. [Find an algorithm to write a given word with this broken keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55674717/3789665). Don't cross-post without giving the first user community a chance to answer.

Comment: As you might have seen, on SO I got 3 downvotes in 30m without any justification so I felt it was the wrong place: I believe SO community does not like this question, even if I do not understand why

Comment: (I am with you re. comments for down-votes. One requirement for questions is *answerable* - ***I*** don't see that, here:) What is *word*? (`a` figures in my dictionary.) Can I delegate the task to [fellow primates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)?

Comment: You have raised more than one point, so please allow me to comment on them in different comments. 
Let's start with answerability: as stated in question intro, it is an interview question so it has to be answerable, furthermore the goals are explicitly stated in the dedicated section. 
As I have also specified in my answer, the problem seems to me very broad so I believe there is room for improvement both checking my strategy and improving it to cover the not yet covered cases.

Comment: I am not talking about this question, however it is not true that an interview question has to be answerable in the sense of this site since "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site". Many interview questions are designed to stimulate chatty two-way communications.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach

## Analysis

This implicitely means finding the button to char mapping the keyboard follows

As it is stated, the problem can be of an arbitrary complexity as we have no prior information about this transfer function, in fact it could be

- random or have a random component
- stateful, so the result could depend on the history

Let's however start focusing on a simple subset of transfer functions which have the following features

- deterministic
- stateless

We can model this as follows, in Haskell terms

`f :: Char -> Char`

However there is an additional problem regarding this function: it is possible any char we need is not represented, i.e. there is no input for that function so that we obtain the desired char as output

This makes the problem essentially equivalent to a linear search so it's `O(N)` with `N` number of possible input chars for the transfer function hence buttons on this keyboard

## Strategy

The additinal restriction which requires to input a word and not single chars, to observe the output, does not affect the complexity: it is sufficient to identify a set of non overlapping words covering the whole input domain so to get a complete knowledge

At the end of this procedure, we will be able to solve the problem or decide it can not be solved because some chars are not representable